# How to open a class (test.java) from another class

Tags: java, class

Hello I have made a code to learn how to use diffrent functions and I wonder how to open another class in eclipse (HelloWorld.java) from another class (Input.java).

Example:

```
system.out.println("Loading Hello World class...");
Loadclass("HelloWorld");
system.exit(0);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by open ??
do you just want to open the file for viewing or you want to load the file

Comment: I want to run the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. If HelloWorld has any static methods you want to use (or if the class is static), you can just call

```
HelloWorld.methodNameHere(argumentsHere);
```

If those methods are not static, then you need to create a HelloWorld object, and your HelloWorld class needs a constructor to go with it.

```
HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
```

after which you can use that object and any methods associated with the class.